# Logstash - Error "Expected one of [ \t\r\n], "#"

Tags: logstash

I use Docker to build my Logstash 7.10.1 image, I overrided logstash.conf with :

```
input {
  uri => "mongodb://admin:pass@localhost:27017/programs?ssl=true"
  placeholder_db_dir => "/opt/logstash-mongodb/"
  placeholder_db_name => "logstash_sqlite.db"
  collection => "programs"
  batch_size => 5000
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://elasticsearch-crawlers:9200"]
    index => "programs"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

I have this error :

> [logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action
> {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
> :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError",  :message=>"Expected one
> of [ \t\r\n], "#", "input", "filter", "output" at line 1,
> column 1 (byte 1)",
> :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in
> `compile_imperative'",  "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in` initialize'",
> "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in  `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in` initialize'",
> "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in
> `execute'",  "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:365:in` block
> in converge_state'"]}

I am on Window, I used Notepad++ to create this `logstash.conf` file. I used `Convert with BOM` and I am on `Unix (LF)` format.

I don't see what is the problem here ? I checked this thread : [Logstash exception Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 1, column 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327808/logstash-exception-expected-one-of-input-filter-output-at-line-1-column-1), but it seems my file is correct

Answer (score 3):

Your config is missing the input plugin type, it seems that you are using the `mongodb` input plugin.

Your config should be something like this.

```
input {
    mongodb {
        uri => "mongodb://admin:pass@localhost:27017/programs?ssl=true"
        placeholder_db_dir => "/opt/logstash-mongodb/"
        placeholder_db_name => "logstash_sqlite.db"
        collection => "programs"
        batch_size => 5000
    }
}
```